# React Redux app structure multiple roles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm planning to do a SPA web app using react redux, I'm stuck at figuring out the right architect for the front end.

So the app can have user to bid product, and admin to approve or manage product. How would the app structure like?

```
actions
- admin
- user
reducers
- admin
- user
containers
- admin
- user
components
route.js //load admin or user
userStore.js
adminStore.js
```

Is above structure make sense? route.js will detect role and load relevant route, then in each redux related folder like actions, reducers, store have to have 2 version.

Comment: As far as I know, redux says : "single source of truth", that means that you have one store (multiple reducers), so in my opinion, your structure is fine, but you should have to merge your stores.

Comment: @Yossi multiple store for multiple redux app, which means I don't really 2 store for an app.

Comment: So what do the adminStore / userStore does?

Comment: adminStore for admin userStore for user? it's has 2 different set of business logic

Comment: I understood that each has diffrent bussiness logic, but they both use createStore?

Comment: @Yossi createStore receive different reducers, pls note that userApp and AdminApp has ntg to do with each other.

Comment: You are right, but you hadn't mention that userStore and adminStore are reducers, you have in reducers folder admin and user.. If it is the case and you will use once create store, I am fine with your structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Webpack you can try multiple `src` and `entry` like that:

```
src-admin
 - actions
 - reducers
 - containers
 - components
 - ...
 - adminRoute.js
 - admin.js
src-user
 - actions
 - reducers
 - containers
 - components
 - ...
 - userRoute.js
 - user.js
webpack.config.js
```

and in webpack.config.js:

```
entry: {
  app: ['./src-user/user.js', '.src-admin/admin.js'],
  vendors: ['react']
}
```

Comment: @JennyMok, if Emad posted the answer to your problem, please check it off as the correct one.